# How to make separate copy of JSON and stop it from getting modified in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Either I am making a blunder here, or might be misusing Angularjs. I want to make a copy of JSON on page load,create form using original one ,and on submit button press ,I will compare these 2 JSONs to check if they are same or not ,on the basis of that I will hit the DB.

Problem: No matter how I create a copy of JSON, when ever I update field in original json,it get updated in it's copy too. Hence on submit button press , method don't find these 2 json different so don't hit the DB,Data don't get saved.

```
Code: 
var globalJsonHRA =null;

//On succcess of $http

globalJsonHRA = data["3"]; 
$rootScope.jsonOfHRA = data["3"];
```

what's wrong with my code??

More Details:
//This is where value is set to JSON on html page

```
<tbody  ng-repeat="obj in jsonOfHRA" my-Post-Repeat-Directive>

                            <tr class="BG8">    
                                <td ><input     type="text" ng-model="obj.sec10_decl_decl_val"  id="rent_{{$index}}" ></td>

                            </tr>       
        </tbody>

//From making a copy I mean,data["3"] is set to 2 different JSONs, so they are copies of each other. For comparison I was using _.isEqual method of underscoreJs, But even I simply alert these 2 jsons ,I find them containing equal values.
```

Comment: provide more code showing where you do the copying and where you do the equality checks

Comment: @scartag Yes I have added more details.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, therefore you need to clone them if you want a unique copy.

Comment: @chovy is that what Angular.copy do?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `angular.copy` is for. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use angular.copy

```
$rootScope.jsonOfHRA = angular.copy(data["3"]);
```

Comment: Thanks Arun,for your suggestion. Haven't tried it though.What Scartag said,worked.

Comment: @Rishi Prakash: As you *are* using angular, if this works it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this works too, and cleaner than the answer I accepted. But Scartag helped me first, Arun answered after scartag. :) Both answers are good. Accepting must not be an issue here. :)

Comment: @Rishi Prakash: I think you miss my point. If one answer is clearly more suited to the original question (was *is* using angular), then a change of answer is appropriate (especially when this one was posted first). The purpose of SO is to provide a source of best/correct answers for others too. So +1 for this answer :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ok, Got that. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it is probably the same reference and that's why they change whichever one you modify.

You could try a deep copy.

```
globalJsonHRA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data["3"]));
$rootScope.jsonOfHRA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data["3"]));
```

Comment: Yes,You are right. It was most probably due to same reference.

Answer (score -1):

Please write the code into Success callback method of $http

```
globalJsonHRA = data["3"]; 
$rootScope.jsonOfHRA = data["3"];
```

Like

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    globalJsonHRA = data["3"]; 
    $rootScope.jsonOfHRA = data["3"]; 
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

and use data after success the $http request.

Comment: what's your point?? I have done the same already.It doesn't answer my qus.

Comment: Store new json data and old json data in different variable and check it.